# Identify Story: Nanotech salvages destroyed and creates new weapons from a battlefield

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find the novel (or maybe short story?) where nanotechnology is used to salvage weapons from a battlefield and create new weapons from their raw materials. I think the setting was on Earth with no aliens involved.  Story was probably written pre-www in the 80's or early 90's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slant, by Greg Bear, had several scenes where military grade nanotechnology was used to destroy hostile forces and, after breaking those forces down, create friendly, robotic allies.